# Why does Temporal not extend Comparable in Java 8 jsr310

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

The documentation for [java.time.temporal.Temporal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html) contains the following note:

> Implementation Requirements: [...] All implementations must be Comparable.

Why does Temporal not just extend Comparable?

**Background:** I want to work with comparable temporals (not with subtypes like LocalDateTime etc.) and have to resort to a somewhat illegible type `<T extends Temporal & Comparable<T>>` which also messes up NetBeans' auto-complete feature.

**Edit:** I want to implement a temporal interval. The obvious implementations for contains(Interval i), contains(Temporal t), overlaps(...), adjoins(...) etc. use Comparable::compareTo(Comparable c) to compare the start and end points, but for interoperability (toDuration(), parse(CharSequence cs)) I need e.g. Duration::between(Temporal s, Temporal e) or SubtypeOfTemporal::parse(CharSequence cs) (yielding Temporal).

Comment: _I want to work with comparable temporals (not with subtypes like LocalDateTime etc.)_: could you explain more specifically?

Comment: If it implemented Comparable<Temporal>, every suclass instance would have to be comparable any other subclass instance. And comparing an Instant with a LocalDate doesn't make sense. Given that the contract mandates that they are comparable, you can cast T to Comparable<T> and safely ignore the compiler warning.

Comment: @assylias: right. What started as a comment ended as an answer. I reposted it as an answer.

Comment: I don't know why you need to work with `Temporal`. Really, the JSR-310-designers want you to work with concrete types only. On that level `Comparable` is always implemented (but not always with self-referencing Generics,  see class `LocalDate`!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer of @JBNizet was very obscure for me on first glance because he advises to do a simple type-cast to `Comparable` (ignoring compiler warning) and generally I would prefer code without any type-casts or warnings (they are not out there just for fun), but first now I find the time to investigate the whole thing more carefully. Let's consider following simple interval example:

```
public class FlexInterval<T extends Temporal & Comparable<T>> {

    private final T from;
    private final T to;

    public FlexInterval(T from, T to) {
        super();
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public boolean contains(T test) {
        return (this.from.compareTo(test) <= 0) && (this.to.compareTo(test) >= 0);
    }
}
```

On that base (preferred by OP as far as I have understood him) it is logical that the compiler will reject first line in following code:

```
FlexInterval<LocalDate> interval = 
  new FlexInterval<LocalDate>(today, today); // compile-error
System.out.println(interval.contains(LocalDate.of(2013, 4, 1));
```

The reason is that `LocalDate` does not implement `Comparable<LocalDate>` but `Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>`. So if we go instead with the approach of @JBNizet and write with the simplified upper bound for T (just Temporal) and then use type-erasure at runtime:

```
public class FlexInterval<T extends Temporal> {

  ...

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // code smell!
  public boolean contains(T test) {
    Comparable<T> t1 = (Comparable<T>) this.from;
    Comparable<T> t2 = (Comparable<T>) this.to;
    return (t1.compareTo(test) <= 0) && (t2.compareTo(test) >= 0);
  }
}
```

This code compiles. And at runtime:

```
FlexInterval<LocalDate> interval = 
  new FlexInterval<LocalDate>(today, today);
System.out.println(interval.contains(LocalDate.of(2013, 4, 1));
// output: false
```

All fine? No. A negative example demonstrates the **unsafety** of the new generic `FlexInterval`-signature (the compiler warning has its reason). If we just choose an abstract type at runtime (some users might do this in "universal" (bad) helper classes):

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
FlexInterval<Temporal> interval = new FlexInterval<Temporal>(today, today);
System.out.println(interval.contains(LocalDate.of(2013,4,1))); // output: false
System.out.println(interval.contains(LocalTime.now()));
```

... then the code compiles again, but we get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.time.LocalTime can
not be cast to java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate
        at java.time.LocalDate.compareTo(LocalDate.java:137)
        at FlexInterval.contains(FlexInterval.java:21)
```

**Conclusion:**

The type-safety strongly requires self-referencing generics (not supported by JSR-310) AND concrete types. Since JSR-310-team has intentionally avoided generics where ever they can users willing to use JSR-310 should respect this design decision and also avoid generics in their application code. Users are best advised if they just use concrete final types, no general-purpose generified classes (which can not be completely safe).

**Most important lesson: Avoid the interface `Temporal` in any application code.**

To be noted: The hostile attitude over for generics is not my personal view. I myself can well imagine a time library which is generified. But this is another subject we don't speak about in this topic.

Answer (score 10):

If it implemented `Comparable<Temporal>`, every suclass instance would have to be comparable with any other subclass instance. And comparing an Instant with a LocalDate, for example, doesn't make sense.

Given that the contract mandates that they are comparable, you can cast `T` to `Comparable<T>` and safely ignore the compiler warning.

Comment: No, you cannot safely cast every temporal type T to Comparable<T>, the class `LocalDate` is a counter example (`Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>`). Generics are not well supported in JSR-310 (by intention).

Comment: @MenoHochschild but thanks to type erasure, that won't cause any problem. See https://gist.github.com/jnizet/a5bac068123afdc36421 for an example.

Comment: You should test it with different concrete types like `LocalDate` and `MinguoDate`.

Comment: Do it, and you'll see that it's OK.

Answer (score 6):

Attempts were made to implement `Comparable`, but because Java does not have self-type generics, it was necessary to have `Temporal` generified by its subtype (like `Enum`). In practice, this was not a good trade off, as in 95%+ usages of `Temporal`, the generified parameter would be unknown and thus `Temporal<?>`. Since the only generified solution was verbose and impractical to most users, it was not retained.

As JB Nizet's answer says, you can just cast to `Comparable` in most cases. Providing the two inputs to `compareTo` are of the same concrete type, you should see no problems.

On intervals, my suspicion is that a `LocalDateRange`, an `InstantInterval` and a `LocalTimeInterval` have less in common than might be imagined and a generified solution is probably worse than coding three separate classes. Remember that is OK to choose against using generics providing the the trade-offs have been considered.

Comment: What possible problems do you see with a generified solution? With the somewhat cluttered type restrictions mentioned above I get a usable interval implementation ... I do not want to put too much functionality into it; only what I wrote in my question ...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
public class TemporalRange<T extends Temporal & Comparable<? super T>> implements Iterable<T>
```

The class then provides an `Iterator<T>` and `Spliterator<T>`, in addition to `stream()` and `parallelStream()` methods. I require type casts to `(T)` when I'm using the `plus()` method, but the `java.time` package does that as well, so hey.

It can be found here: https://github.com/SeverityOne/time-ext

Still in its infancy at the time of writing, not much in terms of unit tests, and no checking against endless loops.